# Different Android Id in Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, deviceid, android-identifiers

I have used two application from playstore named "Device Id" and one self made apk to fetch android id using SECURE.ANDROIDID but every time I am getting different android id(device id) in Android 9 and 10. Though it is coming same for Android 5 and 7.

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Making [`ANDROID_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) change is a deliberate privacy feature [added in Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#privacy-all):

> For apps installed on a device running Android 8.0, the value of `ANDROID_ID` is now scoped per app signing key, as well as per user. The value of `ANDROID_ID` is unique for each combination of app-signing key, user, and device. As a result, apps with different signing keys running on the same device no longer see the same Android ID (even for the same user).